# Symfony doctrine is not doing insert / update / delete

Tags: symfony, doctrine, crud

I was working on a symfony project last month, I could CRUD data with my entities.
But now, I can't insert, update or delete a data.
I can only read data, everything is fine to read it.

When I submit a form, no error is displayed.

I tried to submit a form to create an idea. No idea is created. But when I tried to return the data json when I submit my form, the date is good, but no changes in my database.

I don't know since when I have this problem, all these forms worked a few weeks ago.

Does anyone know why ?

Example of a route :

```
    /**
     * @Route("/{projet}/{id_projet}/idee/nouvelle",name="projet_idee_nouvelle")
     */
    public function projet_idee_nouvelle(int $id_projet,Request $request, ObjectManager $manager){
        $idee=new Idee();

        $repository = $this
        ->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('App:Projet')
        ;
        $projet=$repository->find($id_projet);

        $projets=array();
        array_push($projets,$projet);

        $form=$this->createForm(IdeeType::class,$idee, array(
            'projets'=>$projets
        ));

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $manager->persist($idee);
            $manager->flush();

            //redirection on the created project
            return $this->redirectToRoute('projet_detail',array('id'=>$projet->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('idee/idee_nouveau.html.twig',[
            'form'=>$form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

My "Projet" entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProjetRepository")
 */
class Projet
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $nom;

    //{...} Other class attributes

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Idee", mappedBy="projet", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $projetIdee;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Tache", mappedBy="projet", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $projetTache;
}
```

My Idee entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\IdeeRepository")
 */
class Idee
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Projet")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $projet;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $label;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $texte;
}
```

My twig to add an idea :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Ajouter une idée{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <h1>Ajouter une idée au projet</h1>

    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_row(form.projet, {'label':'Projet associé'})}}
        {{ form_row(form.label, {'label':'Label de l\'idée','attr':{'placeholder':'Label de l\'idée'}}) }}
        {{ form_row(form.texte, {'label':'Description','attr':{'placeholder':'Description'}}) }}
        <button class="button_form" type="submit">Ajouter l'idée</button>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

My IdeeType :

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Idee;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;

class IdeeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('projet',ChoiceType::class,array(
                'label'=>'Projet associé',
                'choices'=>$options['projets'],
                'choice_label' => 'nom',
                'required'=>true
            ))
            ->add('label',TextType::class,array(
                'required'=>true
            ))
            ->add('texte',TextareaType::class,array(
                'required'=>true
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Idee::class,
            'projets'=>null
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your route is not accepting the `POST` request method data. You can check that by issuing `php bin/console debug:router` and check what http method(s) your route is accepting.

Comment: All my routes are accepting POST request. Currently, they accept any http methods.

Comment: Then is because of the `$manager` variable. Try, after `$idee=new Idee();` to get the doctrine as `$doctrine = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()`, and use this for `find()` method and for `persist()` and `flush()`.

Comment: I tried, but it still doesn't work. Perhaps it's a ressource problem, I will check that

Comment: Just for reference, which Symfony are you using? Symfony 2?

Comment: I'm using symfony 4.8.2

Comment: I see, then yes, it won't works... You're totally wrong in what you did... Will write a correction, give me a few mins

Comment: It worked one month ago... I will have many routes to change so... Thank you !

Comment: You cannot pass a whole object to this: `'action'=>$this->generateUrl('projet_idee_nouvelle', array('projet'=>$projet)),`. Instead try, `$projet->getId()` or something similar. And I suggest you use the `doctrine:generate:crud` terminal command in order to see how symfony handles this type of CRUD operations.

Comment: I'm just noticing this with the `Projet` entity but, there is no relation between `Projet` and `Idee` it seems. Wouldn't the problem, and why my answer doesn't works, comes from that? Or is it just that it's not bi-directionnal?

Comment: I updated `Projet` and `Idee`, you can see them in my post.

Comment: Why, in `IdeeType`, do you write `add('projet')`? Your `Projet` is already supplier by your route. So, all you have to do, after `$form->isValid()`, is to write `$idee->setProjet($projet)`, and thus remove `add('projet')` from your form builder. There is no need to create a select just for one `Projet`. Each `Idee` can only have one associated `Projet`

Comment: I changed it :)

Comment: @DanCostinel I tried `make:crud` instead of `doctrine:generate:crud`, it created to my projet the controller. I used the form to add an Idee, but still no error and nothing add in my database.

Comment: Have you set up your database connection? in `.env` file or something similar?

Comment: Yes. I can display data from my database.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry to say that I'm out of ideas as to why it's not working. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I will be blunt about it, but the way you code with Symfony 4 is totally wrong...
You would do best to form yourself on Symfony 4 asap.
You will only ends-up with problems if you keep it that way.

With autowiring, which is enabled by default in Symfony 4, you can pass almost anything as parameter to your fonction (controllers, repositories, etc).

Here, I changed the parameters of your function. Removed `ObjectManager` as it's already part of the extended `AbstractController`, added `ProjetRepository` and `Projet`.

It's strongly advised to always set `action` for your form. 'method' is just a bonus.

I also divided `isSubmitted()` and `isValid()`, which will allow you to return a custom response in case of invalid submitted form.

This is how your code should looks like:

```
use App\Entity\Idee;
use App\Entity\Projet;
use App\Form\IdeeType;
use App\Repository\ProjetRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class IdeeController extends AbstractController {
    /**
     * @Route("/{nom}/{id}/idee/nouvelle",name="projet_idee_nouvelle", methods={"GET", "POST"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @param ProjetRepository $projetRepository
     * @param Projet $projet
     * @return RedirectResponse|Response
     */
    public function nouvelleIdee(Request $request, ProjetRepository $projetRepository, Projet $projet) {
        $idee=new Idee();
        $projets=array();
        array_push($projets, $projet);

        $form=$this->createForm(IdeeType::class, $idee, array(
            'action'=>$this->generateUrl('projet_idee_nouvelle', array('id'=>$projet->getId())),
            'method'=>'POST',
            'projets'=>$projets,
        ));

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isSubmitted()) {
            if($form->isValid()) {
                $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($idee);
                $em->flush();

                //redirection on the created project
                return $this->redirectToRoute('projet_detail', array('id'=>$projet->getId()));
            } else {
                //ToDo Return 404 or error message, etc...
            }
        }

        return $this->render('idee/idee_nouveau.html.twig', array(
            'idee'=>$idee,
            'projet'=>$projet,
            'form'=>$form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

In your twig, your link to your page should looks like this :

```
<a href="{{ path('projet_idee_nouvelle', { 'nom': projet.nom, 'id': projet.id }) }}">Ajouter une idée</a>
```

In case you want to keep url parameters in a way that you can understand them, you would change this :

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
```

---

```
/**
 * @Route("/{projet_nom}/{projet_id}/idee/nouvelle",name="projet_idee_nouvelle", methods={"GET", "POST"})
 * @ParamConverter("projet", options={"mapping": {"nom", "projet_nom", "id": "projet_id"}})
 */
```

---

```
<a href="{{ path('projet_idee_nouvelle', { 'projet_nom': projet.nom, 'projet_id': projet.id }) }}">Ajouter une idée</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for this correction ! I have this  error : "App\Entity\Projet object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation.". I will search tomorrow, I have to sleep, thank you again !

Comment: I already add my Projet Entity in the use. (see the code in the next comment)

Comment: I followed your code. How I am supposed to send an object for the route ? I don't know how it should look like in the url and in my code (for the href)..

Comment: @Piwatte add your projet entity to your question please (again). I need to know the right name of fields to correct the `@Route` parameter

Comment: I added my projet entity

Comment: I still can't add ideas, but I have no error displayed

Comment: Is there no information at all when you open the profiler @Piwatte?

Comment: I don't find any information when I open the profiler :-/

Comment: Xmmm... Then your problem is most likely elsewhere then... Because the code I provided is right. Beside the few custom lines you needs, it's all the basic code of Symfony. You might try to add `IdeeeType.php` to your question. The problem might be in the form builder @Piwatte

Comment: I updated my post, you can show my `IdeeType.php` now. I don't think the problem is here because I can't delete an Idee (a thing I don't understand at all)...